# How does the Keras training loop filter the loss values?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I have a keras model set up as follows (TF 1.2.1):

```
import tensorflow.contrib.keras as keras

model = keras.models.Sequential()

...

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.mean_squared_error,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-4))

model.summary()


Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 29, 29, 64)        6336      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 13, 13, 128)       204928    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 11, 11, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 5, 5, 256)         590080    
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 6400)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 12802     
=================================================================
Total params: 1,109,314
Trainable params: 1,109,314
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The output is a simple float vector and it converges as desired. The loss is mean squared error. Example output:

```
 18/100 [====>.........................] - ETA: 30s - loss: 31.5118
 19/100 [====>.........................] - ETA: 29s - loss: 30.7577
 20/100 [=====>........................] - ETA: 29s - loss: 29.7815
 21/100 [=====>........................] - ETA: 28s - loss: 29.0535
 22/100 [=====>........................] - ETA: 28s - loss: 28.1963
 23/100 [=====>........................] - ETA: 28s - loss: 27.3314
 24/100 [======>.......................] - ETA: 28s - loss: 26.7219
 25/100 [======>.......................] - ETA: 28s - loss: 25.9702
 26/100 [======>.......................] - ETA: 27s - loss: 25.4181
 27/100 [=======>......................] - ETA: 27s - loss: 25.0638
 28/100 [=======>......................] - ETA: 27s - loss: 24.6081
 29/100 [=======>......................] - ETA: 26s - loss: 24.0928
```

The loss seems to decrease steadily. However, when I look at the real losses (`keras.callbacks.LambdaCallback@on_batch_end`) it's not so smooth:

```
25.473383
28.051779
20.519075
13.204493
20.74946
21.246254
25.611149
13.194682
13.268744
15.408422
17.183851
11.232637
14.493115
10.196851
```

I tried to dig in the Keras source code but couldn't understand what is happening under the hood. How does Keras filter the actual losses? Where in the source code can I find this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what is actually shown in a progbar is a mean of a loss over all batches performed in a given epoch at the time of printing. (Mean from first 2 after 2 batches, mean from first 3 after 3 epochs and so on). So - you can get the values printed after `n-th` epoch by taking a mean over first `n` loss values. You can read about it [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/generic_utils.py) in a `Progbar` definition.